# How do i create a solr search query using XML notation?

Tags: java, xml, spring, solr

I would like to store solr queries (written in XML notation) on XML file so that i can load the queries inside a Spring web application. is there a standard way of doing this? i can create my own structure in XML and then use java XML binding, but i wanted to know if solr provides a standard way of doing so.
Im using solr 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not provide an existing standard for storing queries in an XML-based format client side.

You have the opportunity to set static queries or query values in the definitions of your requestHandler (i.e. "this filter should be applied to all queries" or "any query must be against these fields"), but that's a server side feature. That feature does however allow you to create several endpoints for a core that are static, pre-defined queries that your clients can access (for example `/solr/core/all_in_stock`).

Answer (score 0):

XML query notation is available starting from Solr 5.5. The relevant JIRA is [SOLR-839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-839) (7 years in the making).